# Polymer Iron list display is incorrect

Tags: polymer

```
<dom-module id="page-list">
<style include="shared-styles"></style>
<style>
 iron-list {
  height: 500px;      
}  
</style>
<template>
    <neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="0">
        <neon-animatable><paper-button id="list-button" raised on-tap="_onOK" >List</paper-button></neon-animatable> 
        <neon-animatable>
          <iron-list id="list" items="[[data]]" as="item">
              <template>
                    <div>
                        Name: <span>[[item.name]]</span>
                    </div>
              </template>
          </iron-list>   
        </neon-animatable>
    </neon-animated-pages>                     
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "page-list",
        attached: function () {
            this.data=[
                    {
                        index: 0,
                        name: "Liz Grimes"
                    },
                    {
                        index: 1,
                        name: "Frazier Lara"
                    },
                    {
                        index: 2,
                        name: "Dora Griffith"
                    }];
                    this.$.list.fire('resize');
        },
        behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior
        ],
        properties: {                
            data: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        _onOK: function (e) {
            this.$.pages.selected="1";
        }
    });
</script>
```

After pushing the "List" button, the iron list is expected to be totatlly displayed. Unfortunately, the result is a display of one line with "Name:" and nothing else. If I force the selected page to "1", `<neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="1">` which means that on the first resfresh of the browser, the page with the iron list is displayed, the display is correct : three lines with the correct data.

The issue seems to be related to the fact that on startup, the page with the iron list is not yet displayed.

Anybody knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/issues/115

Please check my suggested solution on github.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
          this.set('data', [...]);
```

instead of

```
          this.data=[...];
```

for Polymer to get notice of data change

Comment: If you replace `neon-animated-pages` with `iron-pages`, the problem disappears.

Comment: We added a log inside the `iron-resize` handler, inside the `iron-list`. The handler is called when changing page, in case of `iron-pages`, and not in case of `neon-animated-pages`. We have also added `on-iron-resize="handler"` to the `neon-animated-pages`, and the handler is called when changing page. It seems that the `iron-resize` event is fired, but not received by the `iron-list`.

Comment: I rebuilt your example in Dart (I don't use Polymer with JS) and it works fine (with the change in my answer). At first I see just the string `Name: ` and after a sec the list is rendered with the names. Polymer from Dart just wraps Polymer.js and therefore should be the same. The used Polymer and elements versions are usually a bit behind.

Comment: It seems to be a bug... The `iron-resize` is not notified to all the elements because of this piece of code in `neon-animated-pages`  :    `this.resizerShouldNotify = function(element) { return element == selectedPage; }`. The `iron-resize` is only notified to pages, but not to elements inside the pages. That's strange...

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is merely a hack, but if you listen to the `iron-resize` event on your `neon-animatable` and then call `notifyResize()` on any child `iron-list` elements you should be able to get around this issue until a more sustainable fix can be made to https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/issues/115